# react-native-webview commands failed to compile, how to fix?

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

someone has fixed or saw this issue?

I'm using last version of (react-native) and also macOS Catalina.
I did install ***react-native-webview*** by yarn and after into the (./ios) folder I had install the pods.

So build failed, after `react-native run-ios`.

```
    The following build commands failed:
            CompileC /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cnketoyhxyitfqbbcdkdvhpuajey/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-webview.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNCWebView.o /Users/mymac/Desktop/React/project/node_modules/react-native-webview/apple/RNCWebView.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    (1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the latest version of Xcode?

See react-native-webview issue [#1399](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1399)

Comment: I did downgrade my MacOS to Mojave , and also reinstalled all of the requirements again. Now looks like working nice.
Tks ;)